# Does Express have converter like Spring MVC?

Tags: node.js, spring, express

In Sping MVC we can use "@RequestParam CustomeObject customObject", so the Spring Framework can assemble the customObject from the request parameters. Does Express have any plugin can do this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm no Spring MVC guru, but it looks like `@RequestParam` lets you access query parameters or parameters in the body of a request.

So `http://example.com?name=Enosh` you would need a `@RequestParam("name")` to get that passed into your method as a parameter.

Assuming that it correct...

Your typical express route declaration looks like:

```
app.get( 'users/:id', function iAmExecutedWhenTheUserCallsThisEndpoint( req, res, next ) {

})
```

And the user calls this with `http://example.com/users/42?expanded=true`

To get the `:id` part, use `req.params.id` <-- note this matches up with `:id`. See the [Express documentation on req.params](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.params)

To get the `expanded` part, `req.query.expanded`. See the [Express documentation on req.query](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.query).

So: to answer your question: everything lives off the request object passed into your function, and your function will only ever get called with three parameters: `req`, `res`, and `next`, above.